# The price is not getting dynamically updated when the dropdown is changes in WooCommerce Product Detail page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created a WooCommerce plugin for dynamic pricing I wanted to show the changing price based on dropdown selection. I created the Ajax but it is not working. As the prices are fetched from the database and calculations happen in code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_to_cart_product_pricing');
function add_to_cart_product_pricing()
{
    global $product;
    wp_enqueue_style('my-plugin-styles', plugins_url("jewellery_pricing/assets/css/diamond_style.css", __FILE__));

    // Targeting "ring" or "rings" product category
    if (is_product() && has_term(array('ring', 'rings'), 'product_cat')) {

        extract(get_all_product_data($product, true));


        $metal_purity_percent  = get_metal_purity($metal_purity); // Metal Purity percent
        $gold_value    = ($gold_rate * $metal_purity_percent) / 100; // Gold value

        $finalgold = $gold_value * $net_weight;



        // printf('<p class="gold-price" style="font-size: 28px;">%s</p>', get_displayed_price_html($finalgold, $product));


        echo '<div class=" row">';

        echo '<div class="col-md-6"><label class="label_style" for="ring-size">' . __("Ring Size") . ':</label><br>
        <select id="ring-size" name="ring_size" onchange="updateDescription()" class="selectoptionfield">';

        // Loop through ring sizes
        foreach (get_ring_sizes() as $ring_size) {
            printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $ring_size, selected($ring_size, $def_ring_size), $ring_size);
        }
        echo '</select></div>';


        echo '<div class="col-md-6"> <label for="metal-purity">' . __("Metal Purity") . ':</label><br>
        <select id="metal-purity" name="metal_purity" onchange="updateDescription()" class="selectoptionfield">';

        // Loop through metal purity       
        foreach (get_metal_purity_14k_18k() as $purity) {
            printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $purity, selected($purity, $metal_purity), $purity);
        }
        echo '</select></div>';


        echo '<div class="col-md-12"><label for="diamond-quality">' . __("Diamond Quality") . ':</label><br>
        <select id="diamond-quality" name="diamond_quality" class="selectoptionfield" onchange="updateDescription()">';

        foreach (get_diamondqualityall() as $quality) {
            printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $quality, selected($quality, $diamond_quality), $quality);
        }

        echo '</select></div>';

        echo '
        <input type="hidden" id="updated_gold_price" name="updated_gold_price" value="' . $finalgold. '" />
        </div>';
      }
}
```

Ajax Receiver from where all the action takeplace

```
add_action('wp_ajax_update_gold_price', 'update_gold_price');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_gold_price', 'update_gold_price');
function update_gold_price()
{
    check_ajax_referer('price_calculator_nonce', 'security');

    if (isset($_REQUEST['product_data']) && !empty($_REQUEST['product_data'])) {
        $data = (array) $_REQUEST['product_data'];

        if (
            isset($data['product_id']) && isset($data['ring_size']) && isset($data['metal_purity']) &&
            !empty($data['product_id']) && !empty($data['ring_size']) && !empty($data['metal_purity'])
        ) {
            $product = wc_get_product(intval($data['product_id']));

            // Get necessary product data, converting each element to usable variables (incl gold rate)
            extract(get_all_product_data($product, true));

            $ring_size       = esc_attr($data['ring_size']); // Get selected "metal purity"
            $metal_purity    = esc_attr($data['metal_purity']); // Get selected "metal purity"

            // Load data from custom tables for further calculations
            $metal_purity_percent = get_metal_purity($metal_purity); // Metal Purity percentage
            $ring_grams_percent   = get_ring_grams_percentage($ring_size);


            $gold_value    = (($gold_rate * $metal_purity_percent) / 100);  // Calculate gold value

            // Get calculated updated price
            if ($def_ring_size < $ring_size) {
                $net_weight_1  = $net_weight + $ring_grams_percent;
                $updated_gold_price = $gold_value * $net_weight_1;
            } elseif ($def_ring_size === $ring_size) {

                $updated_gold_price = $gold_value * $net_weight;
            } else {
                $net_weight_2  = $net_weight - $ring_grams_percent;

                $updated_gold_price = $gold_value * $net_weight_2;;
            }


            $data = json_encode(array(
                'raw' => $updated_gold_price,
                'html' => get_displayed_price_html($updated_gold_price, $product)
            ));
            echo $data;
        }
    }
}
```

price-calculator.js

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  if (typeof wc_price_calculator_params === 'undefined') return false;

  var ringSize = $('select#ring-size').val(),
    metalPurity = $('select#metal-purity').val(),
    diamondQty = $('select#diamond-quality').val(),
    productId = $('button[name=add-to-cart]').val();

function updateGoldPrice(ringSize, metalPurity, productId) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: wc_price_calculator_params.ajax_url,
      data: {
        action: 'update_gold_price', // Add a new action for updating gold price
        product_data: {
          product_id: productId,
          ring_size: ringSize,
          metal_purity: metalPurity,
        },
        security: wc_price_calculator_params.nonce,
      },
      success: function (res) {
        var response = $.parseJSON(res);
        $('input#updated_gold_price').val(response['raw']);
        $('p.gold-price').html(response['html']); // Update gold p0rice
        $('form.cart').unblock();
      },
      error: function (err) {
        $('form.cart').unblock();
        console.log(err); // Log errors
      },
    });
  }
  $('form.cart').on('change', 'select#ring-size', function () {
    ringSize = $(this).val();
    updateGoldPrice(ringSize, metalPurity, productId);
  });

  $('form.cart').on('change', 'select#metal-purity', function () {
    metalPurity = $(this).val();
    updateGoldPrice(ringSize, metalPurity, productId);
  });

  $('form.cart').on('change', 'select#diamond-quality', function () {
    diamondQty = $(this).val();
    sendSelectedData(ringSize, metalPurity, diamondQty, productId);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by identifying **which part is not working**:

- **Does the Ajax fire** at all (you can console.log on form change)? - IF it does not have you enqueued the wc_price_calculator_params AJAX as per Wordpress standarts: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/298975/122221
- If the Ajax fires **does it return the correct values**? - If yes, we proceed to the JS success handler, if not you should take a look at the Ajax PHP handler.
- The most common way to address and issue in the JS response is to **console.log everything** and find where you have a bug.

Comment: I also have other Ajax running but they are fine there is only problem with this code @alex it gives me error of bad request 400